# Using CURSOR (part2) to insert statement in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I want to write this stored procedure with a cursor in the `INSERT` statement.

When I `EXEC InsertCustomers_Cursor @cust` this stored procedure, I get this error:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 61
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@cust".

Which means I need to declare the scalar variable of `@cust`, but when I put an ID no also cannot run the query.

```
EXEC InsertCustomers_Cursor @cust = 1;
```

I still got the error message when execute this stored procedure.

```
create table customer 
(
     cust_id int primary key,
     name varchar(100),
     country varchar(50)
);

insert into customer 
values (1, 'John Hammond', 'United States'),
       (2, 'Mudassar Khan', 'India'),
       (3, 'Robert Tan', 'Singapore'),
       (4, 'Dennis Rodman', 'Indonesia'),
       (5, 'Michelle Chia', 'Indonesia'),
       (6, null, null);

select * from customer;

CREATE TYPE CustomerType AS TABLE
(
    cust_id int primary key,
    name varchar(100),
    country varchar(50)
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertCustomers 
    @customers CustomerType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO customer
        SELECT * 
        FROM @customers
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertCustomers_Cursor 
    @customers CustomerType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cust_id    int,
            @name       varchar(100),
            @country    varchar(50)

    --DECLARE AND SET COUNTER
    DECLARE @Counter INT
    SET @Counter = 1

    --DECLARE THE CURSOR FOR A QUERY
    DECLARE InsertCustomers CURSOR READ_ONLY
    FOR
    SELECT cust_id, name, country
    FROM @customers

    --OPEN CURSOR
    OPEN InsertCustomers

    --FETCH THE RECORD INTO THE VARIABLES
    FETCH NEXT FROM InsertCustomers
    INTO @cust_id, @name, @country

    --IF THE FETCH WAS SUCCESSFUL
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO customer (cust_id, name, country) 
        VALUES (@cust_id, @name, @country)

        --ACCESS THE @customers ROWS ONE AT A TIME
        FETCH NEXT FROM InsertCustomers 
        INTO @cust_id, @name, @country
    END

        CLOSE InsertCustomers
        DEALLOCATE InsertCustomers
END
GO

DECLARE @cust CustomerType
INSERT INTO @cust values (7, 'Michael Labone', 'Indonesia');

--EXEC InsertCustomers_Cursor @cust
EXEC InsertCustomers_Cursor @cust
```

Comment: Why even bother with a cursor here?? It's totally unnecessary, it doesn't perform better, it adds no benefits or value...... just use your `InsertCustomers` stored procedure and be done with it!

Answer (score 0):

Now is the time to start reading the documentation and learning the tsql language. You cannot write random code and expect it to work. And when you encounter an error, you should be learning how to diagnose and debug your code. This is no different from any other language.

Your procedure is declared with a single parameter - which is not named @cust. Nor is that parameter of a scalar, numeric type - which is how the engine interprets the literal "1" you attempted to pass.

You declared the parameter as a table type - so you will need to declare and populate a local table type variable in order to pass the specified ID values to the procedure. And since you have not marked an answer to your previous question, then perhaps you should give some thought as to your proper role in a public forum such as SO. If your question was answered, then it is expected that you mark it as such. If not answered, then why start another thread? In addition, take the comments that have been made to heart. Cursors are a topic that require you master basic tsql before you attempt them. If when you have mastered basic tsql, cursors are rarely an appropriate technique to employ.

And to answer your follow up question, learn to search the internet and find your own answers. Almost every question you might have has already been discussed somewhere. The first place to look is the documentation - which often has quite good examples. How do you use user-defined table types? Again - go to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine) which has an example.